# ("Document not defined" in renderer.js) - Sending data and rendering it in electron

Tags: javascript, html, electron, ipc

I am trying to create a Debug app for Body Positioning Data. This data is received as JSON via MQTT in my `receiveAndConversion.js`. I was able to receive the data properly and print to console. So far so good. But now I want in my main window the values that I receive to show up (make the screen green for example when hand closed).

I have tried a lot of things including ipc and adding
`nodeIntegration: true, contextIsolation: false, enableRemoteModule: true,` as preferences in `main.js`

Researching this is kind of a pain, as I always get to questions where the person tries to change the DOM from `main.js` instead of the renderer.
I am new to electron and have been spending hours on the documentation but all their examples are either triggerd on launch of the app or by a button (user interaction). I need to change the DOM when a new message is received, independent on user interaction or other things.

My structure at the moment is like this:

- main.js
- receiveAndConversion.js
- index.html
- renderer.js

Except for `receiveAndConversion.js`, `renderer.js` and the mentioned Preferences in `main.js`, the code is more or less the same as [The quick start guide](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/quick-start).

The main issue that seems to block me is, that I cant seem to be able to call my renderer.js from my receiveAndConversion.js `mqttClient.on()` which runs when I have received a new message. My thinking was I could just call from there a render function in render.js but as it is called from receiveAndConversion.js I get a "document is not defined" error (at least I believe that's the reason).

I would really appreciate if you had an idea for me on how to implement this without having to put everything in main.js.

You can find the complete code below.

```
// main.js

// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron')
//const Renderer = require('electron/renderer')

const path = require('path')
const mqttClient = require('./receiveAndConversion.js')

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      //nativeWindowOpen: true,
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')

  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  //
  //ipcMain.handle('left-hand-closed', (event, arg) => {
  //  console.log('left hand is closed');
  //}
  //)
  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', () => {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

```
<!--index.html-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    We are using Node.js <span id="node-version"></span>,
    Chromium <span id="chrome-version"></span>,
    and Electron <span id="electron-version"></span>.

    <!-- Create different field which will be used to visualise if hands are open or not. So one field for left hand one field for right hand. -->
    <div id="left-hand"></div>
    <div id="right-hand"></div>


    <!-- You can also require other files to run in this process -->
    <script src="./renderer.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
//renderer.js

// get info of open or closed hands from receiveAndConversion.js
// then make the left-hand div or right-hand div green or red depending on open or closed
//const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')

// //write something in the divs
// leftHandDiv.innerHTML = 'Left Hand: ' + leftHandClosed
// rightHandDiv.innerHTML = 'Right Hand: ' + rightHandClosed


// ipcRenderer.handle('left-hand-closed', (event, arg) => {
//     leftHandDiv.innerHTML = 'Left Hand: ' + arg
// }
// )
// ipcRenderer.handle('right-hand-closed', (event, arg) => {
//     rightHandDiv.innerHTML = 'Right Hand: ' + arg
// }
// )

function handChange(leftHandClosed, rightHandClosed) {
//get the divs from the html file
const leftHandDiv = document.getElementById('left-hand')
const rightHandDiv = document.getElementById('right-hand')  

    //check if the hand is open or closed
if (leftHandClosed) {
    leftHandDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
    console.log('left hand is closed');
} else {
    leftHandDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
    console.log('left hand is open');

}

if (rightHandClosed) {
    rightHandDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
    console.log('right hand is closed');

} else {
    rightHandDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
    console.log('right hand is open');
}
}

//make handChange() usable outside of the renderer.js
module.exports = {
    handChange
}
```

```
// preload.js

// All of the Node.js APIs are available in the preload process.
// It has the same sandbox as a Chrome extension.
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  
    const replaceText = (selector, text) => {
      const element = document.getElementById(selector)
      if (element) element.innerText = text
    }
  
    for (const dependency of ['chrome', 'node', 'electron']) {
      replaceText(`${dependency}-version`, process.versions[dependency])
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep your `receiveAndConversion.js` file separate from your `main.js` file and send signals via [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) to `index.html`, you need access to Electrons window instance of `index.html`. This can be achieved by using a "getter" method. Separating the creation (and getting) of `mainWindow` into its own file will therefore be needed.

Good use of a `preload.js` script dictates setting `nodeIntegration: false` and `contextIsolation: true`. Additionally, there should be no need to use any form of remote modules. I have re-worked your `preload.js` script to be used only as a form of communication between the main process and render process. Various forms of `preload.js` scripts can be used, but in this instance I have used the most simplified (but not very flexible) approach.

Lastly, not having access to your `receiveAndConversion.js` file, I have mocked a random hand / position data stream.

As you can see, separating domains into their own files can keep the overall application logical, easy to maintain and bug free when adding additional features.

---

`main.js` (main process)

```js
// Require the necessary Electron modules
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;

// Require the necessary Node modules
const nodePath = require('path');

// Require the necessary Application modules
const appMainWindow = require(nodePath.join(__dirname, './main-window'));
const appReceiveAndConversion = require(nodePath.join(__dirname, './receiveAndConversion'));

// Prevent garbage collection
let mainWindow;

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    mainWindow = appMainWindow.create();
    appReceiveAndConversion.run();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        appMainWindow.create();
    }
});
```

---

Having the `create()` and `get` methods of the `mainWindow` in its own file allows for inclusion within any other file that need reference to the `mainWindow`.

`main-window.js` (main process)

```js
// Require the necessary Electron modules
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;

// Require the necessary Node modules
const nodePath = require('path');

let mainWindow;

function create() {
    mainWindow = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, './preload.js')
        }
    });

    mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { mainWindow.show(); })

    return mainWindow;
}

function get() {
    return mainWindow;
}

module.exports = {create, get}
```

---

`receiveAndConversion.js` (main process)

> Mocked...

```js
// Require the necessary Node modules
const nodePath = require('path');

// Require the necessary Application modules
const appMainWindow = require(nodePath.join(__dirname, './main-window'));

let mainWindow;

// Generate a random number
function randomNumber(lower, upper) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (upper - lower + 1) + lower)
}

// An infinitely polled function
function listener() {
    let hand = (randomNumber(0, 1)) ? 'leftHand' : 'rightHand';
    let position = (randomNumber(0, 1)) ? 'opened' : 'closed';

    console.log(hand + ' ' + position); // Testing

    mainWindow.webContents.send(hand, position);
}

// Called from main.js
function run() {
    mainWindow = appMainWindow.get();
    setInterval(() => { listener(); }, 350);
}

module.exports = {run}
```

---

`preload.js` (main process)

A simple (but rigid) example.

```js
// Import the necessary Electron components
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// Exposed protected methods in the render process
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods
    'electronAPI', {
        // From main to render
        leftHand: (position) => {
            ipcRenderer.on('leftHand', position);
        },
        rightHand: (position) => {
            ipcRenderer.on('rightHand', position);
        }
    });
```

---

Instead of changing background colors via JavaScript, it is better to change class names or even better again, data attribute values in this instance.

> For simplicity, I have incorporated a revised `renderer.js` between the `<script>` tags.

`index.html.js` (render process)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"/>
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                height: 100vh;
                display: flex;
                flex-flow: row nowrap;
            }

            #left-hand,
            #right-hand {
                flex: 1 0 50%;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                font-size: 3em;
            }

            #left-hand[data-position="closed"],
            #right-hand[data-position="closed"] {
                background-color: darkred;
            }

            #left-hand[data-position="opened"],
            #right-hand[data-position="opened"] {
                background-color: darkgreen;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="left-hand" data-position="closed">Left Hand</div>
        <div id="right-hand" data-position="closed">Right Hand</div>
    </body>

    <script>
        let leftHand = document.getElementById('left-hand');
        let rightHand = document.getElementById('right-hand');

        window.electronAPI.leftHand((event, position) => {
            console.log('leftHand ' + position); // Testing
            leftHand.dataset.position = position;
        });

        window.electronAPI.rightHand((event, position) => {
            console.log('rightHand ' + position); // Testing
            rightHand.dataset.position = position;
        });
    </script>
</html>
```